# Delphi: Executing Conditional Statements in a String

Tags: string, delphi, conditional-statements, execute, statements

How can I execute in Delphi a conditional statements in a String?

In PHP there is something like this:

```
<?php 
echo "Hello (isset($name) ? $name : 'Guest')); 
?>
```

Comment: PHP has something *like* that, but not actually that. You're missing a closing quotation mark, but even with that added, it won't actually evaluate the `isset` expression in the string. When asking a question, please make sure the claims you make are true in the language you know before asking whether they're true in the language you don't.

Comment: mmm I think I misread the question. Are you asking for an [eval](http://www.php.net/eval) counterpart in delphi?

Comment: @whosrdaddy What else could the question be?

Comment: There's no string escaping/expansion/evaluation in Delphi, so definitely no ternary evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually want to evaluate code that is not known until runtime. That's the only reason why you would have code in a string. If my assumption is correct, then you cannot do that readily in Delphi. Delphi is compiled. So in order to execute Delphi code you need to compile it.

You could consider using a scripting language for this part of your program. There are many available.

Of course, if all you want is a conditional operator in Delphi then there is none built in but the RTL provides [IfThen](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.IfThen):

```
function IfThen(AValue: Boolean; const ATrue: string; 
  AFalse: string = ''): string;
```

> **Description**
>
> Conditionally returns one of two specified values.
>
> **IfThen** checks the expression passed as AValue and returns ATrue if it evaluates to true, or AFalse if it evaluates to false. In Delphi, if the AFalse parameter is omitted, **IfThen** returns 0 or an empty string when AValue evaluates to False.

Comment: Just remember that both arguments are evaluated before executing the function, so it's not the same as the ternary operator (`?:`) in C or C#.

Comment: @afrazier Yes that's true. By the way, the operator's name is actually the conditional operator. It is invariably named incorrectly as the ternary operator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Doesn't Delphi actually have some ability to compile expressions at runtime? http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/a-quick-guide-to-evaluate-and-compile-expressions-using-the-livebindings-expression-evaluator/   https://bitbucket.org/NickHodges/nickdemocode/src/842eb3fc74d7/SampleExpressionEvaluator.dpr?at=default

Comment: @alcalde evaluate at runtime rather than compile at runtime

Answer (score 2):

the closest thing you can get in Delphi is this :

```
Writeln('Hello ' + IIf(Name='', 'Guest', Name));
```

where `IIf` is defined as:

```
function iif(Test: boolean; TrueRes, FalseRes: string): string;
begin
 if Test then
  Result := TrueRes
 else
  Result := FalseRes;
end;
```

Please mind that this example only works with strings...

**EDIT**

As David suggested you can also use the `IfThen` function from the `StrUtils` unit

Comment: I think if you add the "Hello " part to your example, it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For a type independent IIF, use this:

```
function IIF(pResult: Boolean; pIfTrue: Variant; pIfFalse: Variant): Variant;
begin
  if pResult then
    Result := pIfTrue
  else
    Result := pIfFalse;
end;
```